# Configure a remote project

Tags: django, project, remote-access

I am starting a Django project. I'd like to connect this project in such a way my partner could work remotly and we can see the trackings and modifications on that project. What do you suggest to set up those configurations?

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with Django. The usual way of collaborating on a project these days is via something like Github.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, I have already heard about it. If a want to create a webapplication. Could you tell me if I could collaborate with my partner for free?

Answer (score 0):

The program is called git, its not necessary use GitHub, Bitbucket to deploy your Django project in a server, also you can have a version control of your project and work with your patner without problems. Read this to deploy your Django project https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks#using-git-hooks-to-deploy-to-a-separate-production-server and this is git https://git-scm.com/